# encoding error in Mojolicious' template

Tags: perl, template-engine, mojolicious

I have non-ascii characters with utf-8 encoding (Chinese characters), but they're not printed correctly. I have to add `decode('utf8', $str)` (in controller or template file) to get the right output. How could I set the template to recognize utf-8 string?

Anyhow, the literal stashed string can make the rigth output, and I don't know why.
The content are stored in MySQL with utf-8 collection. I added `$DB->do("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");` after database is connected, but no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try DBI option mysql_enable_utf8 set to 1.

Comment: Yes, I've just found the answer! Thank you!

Comment: i.e. $dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1 ;